# latex error(can only be used in preamble)

Tags: errors, warnings, preamble

goodevening to everyone. please when i try running this code below i always have can only be used at the preamble.Please need your help.

```
\documentclass[12pt,A4,english]{report}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[english]{minitoc}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[left=40mm,right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.9cm}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.94cm}
%\setlength {\evensidemargin }{-0.04 cm}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym,verbatim}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{syntonly,indentfirst}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{invoice}
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,txfonts}

%\textheight=22cm \textwidth=16cm
\frenchspacing %\linespread{2}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makeidx}

%\fancyhf{} % cancels header and foot pr\'ed\'efinis
%\fancyhead[L,R]{\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
%\fancyhead[L]{} % Left Odd
%\fancyhead[R]{} % Right Even

%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}% filet en haut de page

%\addtolength{\headheight}{2.pt} % espace pour le filet
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}% filet en bas de page
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % et le filet

%\lhead{\textbf{\thepage}} %{\textsl{\rightmark}}



\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage} %RO=right odd, RE=right even
    
}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

 
 
 % Don't bother to report over-full boxes if over-edge is < 2pt
% Line spacing -----------------------------------------------------------
\newlength{\defbaselineskip}
\setlength{\defbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\setlinespacing}[1]%


\frenchspacing\linespread{1.5}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\thechapterwords}
{ \ifcase \thechapter\or ONE\or TWO\or THREE\or FOUR\or FIVE\or SIX\or SEVEN\or EIGHT\or NINE\or TEN\or ELEVEN\fi}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    %\vspace*{50\p@}%
    %\vspace*{15\p@}%it is to increase  the distance between the to and chapter number
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
        \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapterwords 
        \par\nobreak
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \par
        \vspace*{15\p@}%
                
        \vskip 2\p@
        %\vskip 100\p@
    }}
    \def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
        %\vspace*{50\p@}%
        %\vspace*{15\p@}%it is to increase  the distance between the to and chapter number
        {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
            \par\nobreak
            \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
            \par
            \vspace*{15\p@}%
            
            \vskip 2\p@
            %\vskip 100\p@
        }}
        \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
            %\vspace*{50\p@}%
            %\vspace*{15\p@}%it is to increase  the distance between the to and chapter number
            {\parindent \z@ \centering \reset@font
                \scshape \@chapapp{} \thechapterwords
                \par\nobreak
                \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
                \par
                \vspace*{15\p@}%
                
                \vskip 2\p@
                %\vskip 100\p@
            }}
                \fancyhf{} % supprime les en-tÃƒÂªtes et pieds prÃƒÂ©dÃƒÂ©finis
                \fancyhead[L,R]{\bfseries\thepage}% Left Even, Right Odd
                \fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\rightmark} % Left Odd
                \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\leftmark} % Right Even
                \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% filet en haut de page
                \addtolength{\headheight}{1pt} % espace pour le filet
                %\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}% filet en bas de page
                %\addtolength{\footheight}{0.5pt} % espace pour le filet en bas
                %\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % pages de tetes de chapitre
                    %\fancyhead{} % supprime l'entete
                    %\fancyfoot{} %supprime le pied de page
                    %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
                %}
                \newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
                    \newpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}}        
                %\lhead{\textsl{\leftmark}}     
                %\fancyfoot[RO]{\tiny \textbf{W.}}
                %\fancyfoot[LO]{\tiny \textbf{MSc. Thesis In Mathematics }}
                \rhead{\textbf{\thepage}}
                %\lhead{\textsl{\leftmark}}
            
            
            
        
        
\newcommand{\I}{\textrm{$\mathrm{i}$}}          
\newcommand{\U}{\textrm{$\mathcal{U}$}}     
\newcommand{\N }{\textrm{$\mathbb{N}$}}
\newcommand{\Z }{\textrm{$\mathbb{Z}$}}
\newcommand{\R }{\textrm{$\mathbb{R}$}}
\newcommand{\Q }{\textrm{$\mathbb{Q}$}}
\newcommand{\C }{\textrm{$\mathbb{C}$}}
\newcommand{\vo }{\textrm{$\varOmega$}}
\newcommand{\B }{\textrm{$\mathbb{B}$}}

\newtheorem{thm}{\textbf{Theorem}}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{\textbf{Lemma}}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{\textbf{Proposition}}
\newtheorem{claim}[thm]{\textbf{Claim}}
\newtheorem{result}[thm]{\textbf{Result}}
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{\textbf{Remark}}
\newtheorem{dfn}[thm]{\textbf{Definition}}
\newtheorem{expl}[thm]{\textbf{Example}}
\newtheorem{counter-expl}[thm]{\textbf{Counter-example}}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{\textbf{Corollary}}
\newtheorem{note}{\textbf{Note}}    


    
\pagenumbering{roman}\addtocounter{page}{-1}
 

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{UNIVERSITY OF BUEA}
    \end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
    
\noindent \textbf{FACULTY OF SCIENCE \hspace{2.5cm} DEPARTMENT OF MATHEMATICS}
\vspace{2cm}
    \begin{flushleft}
     {\noindent\textbf{$L^{p}-L^{q}$ RATIONAL OF BERGMAN TYPE OPERATORS OVER THE SIEGEL UPPER HALF-SPACE }}  
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
    
    \textbf{By\\}
    
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace} 
        \textbf{ Tallie Peka Ronald }\\
        \small{B.Sc in Mathematics}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{center}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}
    A Thesis Submitted to the Department of Mathematics, Faculty of
    Science\\
    of the University of Buea in Partial Fulfilment of
    the Requirements\\ for the Award of the Master of Science (M.Sc.)\\ Degree in Mathematics
\end{singlespace}   .
\end{center}
\vspace{2.6cm}

\begin{center}
September, 2020
\end{center}


    \begin{center}
        \textbf{UNIVERSITY OF BUEA}
    \end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
    
\noindent \textbf{FACULTY OF SCIENCE \hspace{2.5cm} DEPARTMENT OF MATHEMATICS}
\vspace{2cm}
    \begin{flushleft}
     {\noindent\textbf{$L^{p}-L^{q}$ BOUNDEDNESS OF BERGMAN TYPE OPERATORS OVER THE SIEGEL UPPER HALF-SPACE }}  
    \end{flushleft}
    \vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
    
    \textbf{By\\}
    
\end{center}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{center}
    \begin{singlespace} 
        \textbf{ Tallie Peka Ronald }\\
        \small{B.Sc in Mathematics}
    \end{singlespace}
\end{center}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{singlespace}
    A Thesis Submitted to the Department of Mathematics, Faculty of
    Science\\
    of the University of Buea in Partial Fulfilment of
    the Requirements\\ for the Award of the Master of Science (M.Sc.)\\ Degree in Mathematics
\end{singlespace}   .
\end{center}
\vspace{2.6cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks Sir,i will try and download tex live

Comment: will try the first option Sir,by making it smaller

Comment: The preamble is everything that comes before `\begin{document}`.  LaTeX is complaining that you are doing something that can only be done in the preamble.  But since you've only shown us your preamble, nothing you've shown us would cause that problem.

Comment: ohh sorry is just that the code is very long. this is it below

Comment: ok ok,thanks  Sir

Comment: copy the document in the question to a new folder and test it, I get no error: are you sure you posted an example of the porblem?

Comment: yes Sir,trying it back again